# Email sending failed (asp.net)

Tags: c#-4.0

This is a code to send email... It works perfect fine in my computer but doesnt work when i upload this code on godaddy serve.

this is the error iam getting

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.205.108:587

(you need to download the EASendMail.dll for your particular network frame for this code to work)

```
    SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
    EASendMail.SmtpClient oSmtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();

    // Your gmail email address
    oMail.From = "SendersAddress@gmail.com";


    // Set recipient email address
    oMail.To = "Recieverseaddress@gmail.com";

    // Set email subject
    oMail.Subject = "Verification Code";

    // Set email body
    oMail.TextBody = "This is a test code";


    // Gmail SMTP server address
    SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");

    // Set 25 port, if you want to use 587 port, please change 25 5o 587
    oServer.Port = 587;

    // detect SSL/TLS automatically
    oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

    // Gmail user authentication
    // For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be the same
    oServer.User = "Sendersaddress@gmail.com";
    oServer.Password = "Password";

    try
    {
        Messagebox("start to send email over SSL ...");
        oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
        Response.Redirect("~/Verification.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ep)
    {
        Messagebox("failed to send email with the following error:");
        Messagebox(ep.Message);
    }
```

Comment: All most all hosting servers will not allow you to send Email using SMTP  because it considered as spamming.